# How I can get Ch340 Virtual Com port interface

Tags: pdf, serial-port

I am debugging the ch340 driver in android (https://github.com/felHR85/UsbSerial).
I need ch340 spec such as this document.  https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/application-notes/AN571.pdf
But `AN571.pdf` is for `cp2102`.

How I can get this document for `ch340`?

Comment: Probably this page. Various materials are published. [USB转串口芯片CH340](http://wch.cn/products/CH340.html)

Comment: Thanks, I checked that, but that is not enough than cp2102 pdf